# SP13 - How to sync 4000 items in list to target list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list-item, variations

I have a list with **4000 items**. The default view in my list has **100 pages**... I must have to go to every page to select the items and update them in another language version. *This will take a long time.*

[image]

**How to select all 4000 items on list?** - Microsoft Documentation has limit to select more than 100 items for bulk operations.

```
Can I do this programmatically with console application?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary) by Microsoft, you cannot select more than 100 items for bulk operations.

The documentation says that:

[image]

Where Boundary means you cannot configure the value. Its hard coded.

[image]

Comment: Can I do this programmatically with console application?

Comment: please have a look to this https://www.sharepointeurope.com/automate-variations-in-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell-c . Its just to get you a basic idea